# audio problem in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, audio

What happens is that I connect my laptop to the TV with HDMI to watch a movie but after disconnecting the HDMI no longer sounds, for example YouTube videos or movies that I have on my laptop, do not reproduce sound, but the sounds of the system do they sound

Comment: Why are you using the specialist pen-testing Kali distribution to watch films?

Comment: I am a student of systems engineering, I am still learning about this distribution

Comment: You'd be better off using another distro. Kali has a very specific use case.

Comment: What kind of distro do you recommend renan?

Comment: **systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio**

Comment: @angelvelasanchez CentOS, Ubuntu, or Debian are all good picks. Find which of these distro your friends use and install that one.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Kali installation have Pulseaudio? Without it, most applications cannot switch from one sound card to another without restarting the application - and a GPU with HDMI outputs is often a "sound card" that is totally separate from the actual integrated sound card that provides analog audio outputs.

The system sounds, on the other hand, typically open the sound device only just when a sound needs to be played, and so they choose their sound card just before a sound begins playing.

Comment: How do I verify that I have the pulseaudio installed? I am new in the world linux

Comment: If you are new in the Linux world, you probably shouldn't have started with Kali.

Comment: What kind of distro do you recommend?

Comment: @angelvelasanchez see that's the problem with directly handling professional distro, not just kali. Even if there was a solution one would has to ask how to run that solution and when solution of a solution is found then one has to question how to run that solution of a solution. Then solution of a solution of a solution.

Comment: (L/K/X/)Ubuntu is one of the most newbie-friendly distros, and since it's already widespread, finding up-to-date instructions and advice will be much easier.  You'll also find that many of the penetration testing tools of Kali are easily installable to Ubuntu too.